# Why mapred.min.split.size doesnt change the number of mappers for my query

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, hdfs

I was doing some deep dive with a simple use case to see how we can control the number of mappers launched in hive.

This is what I did :

**Step1** : Found out how much is the block size of the system.

`hdfs getconf -confKey dfs.blocksize
Output : 134217728 => 128 Megabytes (MB)`

**Step2** : Placed a file of 392781672 bytes (392 MB) in HDFS and created a table on top of it

**Step 3** : Ran a simple count (select count(1) from table) which triggered.

`Mappers : 3
Reducers : 1`

which is as expected.

**Step 4** : Now changed the setting :

`set mapred.min.split.size = 392503151`

`set mapred.max.split.size = 392503000`

**Step 5** : Ran a select count(1) from table and 
it still triggers 3 mappers and 1 reducer.

`Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 3; number of reducers: 1`

**Question** : I would expect this to run only 1 mapper since now the file size and my min max splits size is the same , then why its not following this principle here.

Comment: Which version of hive and hadoop you are using?

Comment: @gyan Hive 1.2 , Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227

Comment: On the console, please run `hdfs getconf -confKey mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` and then `set mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize=392503000` and then `hdfs getconf -confKey mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize` again and post the result.